# Is there a way where we can verify if certain image is 3D or not

Tags: c#, 3d, image, node.js, three.js

I wanted to understand - Is there a way where we can verify if certain image is 3D or not

So basically I want to automate the process where we can detect if certain given image is of 3D or not

Problem: In my application - I often detect few 3D images are showing as plain black image or sometimes 3D images are broken

So if I can find a way where I can check that certain image should not be completely black and should be 3D model and not 2D image

My Application is in C# - but I am open for any solution irrespective of language!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a 3D image in this case? What's the source of these images, what format are they in, etc?

Comment: @DMGregory - for example the image model of 3D looks like shown in link here: https://www.contrado.co.uk/stores/amaishadesigns/winter-659273

Comment: @DMGregory - One more example - https://www.contrado.co.uk/womens-camisoles

Comment: Those are not "images". That's likely a WebGL canvas element. Are you building a game, or a content scraping tool?

Comment: @DMGregory I am not building content scrapping tool, but instead kind of an application - where first we will convert 2D images to 3D - then we will post it to some site for view - but in that what challenge we are facing - at times instead of 3D canvas element - we see completely black image - so we may need to detect if certain element is of 3D or 2d and is not black

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about developing a game or game mod. Please post general application development questions on StackOverflow.